# What does "base passions" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning

What author means by "base passions" in following sentence:

> Philosophy titans such as David Hume thought that **base passions** powered moral decisions.

Above sentence is from Book "Brain Rules for Baby by John Medina"

Answer (score 3):

While the term *[base](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/base#nav2)* can have several meanings, the following seems most apt in your example

> (Of a person or a person’s actions or feelings) without moral principles; ignoble:
>
> *the electorate’s baser instincts of greed and selfishness*
>
> *we hope his motives are nothing so base as money*

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

The phrase *base passions* would generally refer to those drives that are instinctual, if not noble - acquisitiveness, lust, anger, fear.

The reference seems to suggest that these ignoble inclinations can lead to more exalted determinations.